# What is difference between 'data:' and 'data()' in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have used data option in two ways. In first snippet data object contains a key value, however, in second data is a function. Is there any benefits of individuals.Not able to find relevant explanations on Vue.js Docs
Here are two code snippets:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      message: 'hello mr. magoo'
    }

});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'hello mr. magoo'
    }
  }
});
```

Both are giving me the same output.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data 5th paragraph of detail content is what you are looking for.

Comment: so ,data() {
    return {
      message: 'hello'
    } and data: function() {
    return {
      message: 'hello '
    }  both are same?

Comment: yes, data () {} is ES6, data: function is ES5 way of same code.

Comment: Thanks mate. Bdw where can I find detailed instrction on ES6 and ES5 specs? It will be great if you provide any.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It seems as though the comments on your question missed a key point when considering your specific code example.

In a root Vue instance i.e. constructed via `new Vue({ ... })`, you can simply use `data: { ... }` without any problems. The issue is when you have reusable components that are defined via `Vue.component(...)`. In these instances, you need to either use `data() {return { ... };}` or `data: function() {return { ... };}`.

The reason for this is to ensure that for each individual instance of the reusable child component, there is a unique object containing all of the data being operated on. If, in a child component, you instead use `data: { ... }`, that same data object will be shared between the child components which can cause some nasty bugs.

Please review the [corresponding section of the Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) for more information regarding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.**

so initiating a new vue instance dose not matter between data:{} as a object or data(){return{}} or data:function(){return{}}.

It matters when it comes to component lets try an example:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <counter></counter>
        <counter></counter>
    </div>
    <script>
         Vue.component('counter', {
             template: '<button v-on:click="counter += 1">{{ counter }}</button>',
             data: {
                 counter:0
             }
         });
    </script>
```

Output:

```
[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
```

Now lets watch in vue object:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">{{ counter }}</button>
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">{{ counter }}</button>
    </div>
    <script>

        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            /*data() {
                return {
                    counter:0
                }
            },*/
            //or (output same)
            /*data: function () {
                return {
                    counter: 0
                }
            }*/
            //or (output same)
            data:{
                counter:0
            }

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

//Now let's try data as a function in the component to reuse same component over and over again.

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <counter></counter>
        <counter></counter>
        <counter></counter>
    </div>
    <script>

        Vue.component('counter', {
            template: '<button v-on:click="counter += 1">{{ counter }}</button>',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    counter: 0
                }
            }
        })

        new Vue({
            el: '#app'
        });
    </script>

</body>
```